# How to divide pieces of some text as children of a parent tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose given a random text:

```
var v="
Hi this is a text with {
as opening  brace and somewhere I
May have another {
 brace and then again
An {
 brace, but now we have a
}
brace then followed by another
}
 brace and not to forget the last one
}  
    "
```

Now  What I was looking for  is to add a tag for each pair of brace so that it defines its scope:

```
 Hi this is a text with 
 <pre id=”tag1”>
  {
  as opening  brace and somewhere I
  May have another 
 <pre id=”tag2”>
  {
  brace and then again
  An 
<pre id=”tag3”>
  {
  brace, but now we have a
  }
</pre>
  brace then followed by another
  }
</pre>
  brace and not to forget the last one
  }  
</pre>
```

**Why I want to achieve this ?**

I want to get the scope of variables defined  within a pair of  `‘{ }’`. Once I know the scope, I can highlight  the variable on a click within its enclosing tag.:

```
 $('#tag3').highlight(Variable)
```

**My ideas:**

-If encountered a {

-create element “pre” id=0

-extract the text until the matching } is encountered say text

- put this text in innerHTML of pre 0 tag
- For  second  brace { repeat same steps,
- append as a child of pre0
- repeat for all opening and closing brace.

But this a way too complex procedure. Any simple ideas?

Comment: One word my friend: regex

Comment: @beautifulcoder I thought about it, but then concluded won't the regular expression may encounter a non-regular grammar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with replace method

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/a9bk08c4/

```js
var str = $('#t').text();
var res = str.substring(7, 14);
newstr = str;
while (newstr.indexOf("}") > -1) {
    newstr = newstr.replace("}","</pre>");
}
var k = 0;
while (newstr.indexOf("{") > -1) {
    k++;
    newstr = newstr.replace("{","<pre id='"+k+"'>");
    newstr = newstr.replace("}","'>");
}

document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = newstr;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t">Hi this is a text with { as opening brace and somewhere I May have another { brace and then again An { brace, but now we have a } brace then followed by another } brace and not to forget the last one }</div>
```

use inspector tool to see the effect

Comment: To be truthful, I tried this before but without success.I think I left a bug somewhere. Thank you so much for your help prakhar :)